# Load list dynamically in drupal 7 based on the value selected in another list

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi, drupal-forms

Being new to drupal 7 I have the following requirement
I have a business dropdown (list in drupal) based on the selected item in that business list the other list having user should be populated and also there is one more list branches which is in fields collection should also be loaded based on the value selected in the business dropdown.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.

[Demos](http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select).

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a
>   greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.

**Update**

Another option [Simple hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/shs)

Comment: I looked into it but for drupal 7 it is only for Taxonomy and menus, not very sure how to use Taxonomy as such, I tried it but didn't solved my purpose, I guess I will have to look into hook or may be forms api, the solution that was posted in the drupal forums